# .NET Encoding Page Routes?

Tags: .net, asp.net, routes, url-routing, url-encoding

I am using .NET Page Routing (not MVC) to get pretty URLs (or at least removing the file extensions) on my site.

On my search page, when a user searches for "stuff" it redirects then to /search/stuff for the results. However when I put in something like "stuff yes:" it gives me a HTTP 400 Bad Request Error.

I tried using javascript to encode the search value before being submitted, and confirmed that "stuff yes:" was converted to "staff%20yes%3A", yet when it performs the routing redirect, in the URL it shows "staff%20yes:" and causes the bad request. Why is it not saving the encoding for the typically illegal characters and how can I make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.  Is it possible this is happening because the `:` isn't *always* an illegal character in URIs?  For example,

`foo://username:password@example.com:8042`

I'm probably reaching, but it's a thought.

Comment: Okay so you are right, every other character gets encoded properly, a custom replacement on that character : will work fine then.